# Isotope - Loading more than one container on a single page

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-isotope, jquery-masonry

I am calling an isotope layout for multiple containers on the same page. The catch it I would like each container ID to the be the same. Using http://isotope.metafizzy.co v.2.1.0

Isotope will work for the first block, but doesn't trigger for the second block. My feeling is once isotope layout hits the first ID of the first container it stops and doesn't look for the same container again. I've tried using .each() - doesn't seem to want to work however.

```
<div id="isotope-cat-list">
    <div class="grid-sizer"></div>
    <div class="box">
         <h1>TITLE</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
         <h1>TITLE</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

I then need to call another isotope block layout again:

```
<div id="isotope-cat-list">
    <div class="grid-sizer"></div>
    <div class="box">
         <h1>TITLE</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
         <h1>TITLE</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

Full HTML would look like this:

```
<div id="isotope-cat-list">
    <div class="grid-sizer"></div>
    <div class="box">
         <h1>TITLE</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
         <h1>TITLE</h1>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="isotope-cat-list">
    <div class="grid-sizer"></div>
    <div class="box">
         <h1>TITLE</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
         <h1>TITLE</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

Obviously there are more elements in those .box elements but for simplicity sake I whittled it down. The reason for multiple calls is they will be for different categories and have other elements in between then and I'd rather not have to call a bunch of container ID's.

When I try to trigger the #isotope-cat-list in my .js library it will run for the first block - but won't trigger for the second block. I've tried doing some jQuery .each() but that didn't work.

Here's the JS:

```
var mainEl = $('#isotope-cat-list');

mainEl.isotope({
    animationEngine: 'best-available', //CSS3 if browser supports it, jQuery otherwise
    itemSelector: '.box',
    animationOptions: {
        duration: transitionDuration
    },
    containerStyle: {
        position: 'relative',
        overflow: 'visible'
    },
    masonry: {
        columnWidth: columnWidth,
        gutter: 1
    }
});
```

I've tried doing .each():

```
var mainEl = [$('#isotope-cat-list')];

$.each(mainEl, function (j) {
        this.isotope({
        animationEngine: 'best-available', //CSS3 if browser supports it, jQuery otherwise
        itemSelector: '.box',
        animationOptions: {
            duration: transitionDuration
        },
        containerStyle: {
            position: 'relative',
            overflow: 'visible'
        },
        masonry: {
            columnWidth: columnWidth,
            gutter: 1
        }
    });
});
```

But it still doesn't trigger for the second HTML block. Any help here would be much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: You can't use the same ID twice on a page. They are unique.

Answer (score 0):

As I stated, ID's are unique. You can use a class multiple times like so ( some of your functions are missing so I had to modify your code for that reason). You are calling isotope using v1.56 options, not v2.
Updated code

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/macsupport/fx9pjecg/7/)

```
var mainEl = $('.isotope-cat-list');
mainEl.isotope({
itemSelector: '.box',
transitionDuration: '0.3s',
masonry: {
     columnWidth: '.grid-sizer',
    gutter: 10
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using [isotope V2](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/options.html#containerstyle) and it only uses css3 for animations, therefore **you should not apply** `animationEngine or animationOption`. Also you are using `"grid-sizer"` and that **should be what you apply in your columnWidth**. E.g. `columnWidth: '.grid-sizer'`. Also the containerStyle is `position: relative` **as a default**, therefore it is useless to say it in the options. Also the gutter is pointless in your case as you can simply use `margins` in css for your items.

For your question you'd do:

```
var mainEl = $('.isotope-cat-list');
mainEl.isotope({
 itemSelector: '.box',
 masonry: {
  columnWidth: '.grid-sizer'
 }
});

var mainEl2 = $('.isotope-cat-list-2');
mainEl2.isotope({
 itemSelector: '.box',
 masonry: {
  columnWidth: '.grid-sizer'
 }
});
```